# (howto) Get face from input to front camera as UIImage

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avcapturesession, face-detection

I'm resolving task of scanning front camera input for faces, detecting them and getting them as **UIImage**-objects.
I'm using **AVFoundation** to scan and detect faces.

Like this:

```
let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice)
captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
captureSession!.addInput(input)

output = AVCaptureMetadataOutput()
captureSession?.addOutput(output)

output.setMetadataObjectsDelegate(self, queue: dispatch_get_main_queue())
output.metadataObjectTypes = [AVMetadataObjectTypeFace]


videoPreviewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
videoPreviewLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
videoPreviewLayer?.frame = view.layer.bounds
view.layer.addSublayer(videoPreviewLayer!)

captureSession?.startRunning()
```

In delegate method **didOutputMetadataObjects** I'm getting face as **AVMetadataFaceObject** and highliting it with red frame like this:

```
let metadataObj = metadataObjects[0] as! AVMetadataFaceObject
let faceObject = videoPreviewLayer?.transformedMetadataObjectForMetadataObject(metadataObj)
faceFrame?.frame = faceObject!.bounds
```

Question is: How can I get faces as **UIImages**?

I've tried to dance over the '**didOutputSampleBuffer**' but it isn't called at all :c

Answer (score 4):

I did the same thing using didOutputSampleBuffer and Objective-C. It looks like:

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection {
  CVPixelBufferRef pixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);
  CFDictionaryRef attachments = CMCopyDictionaryOfAttachments(kCFAllocatorDefault, sampleBuffer, kCMAttachmentMode_ShouldPropagate);
  CIImage *ciImage = [[CIImage alloc] initWithCVPixelBuffer:pixelBuffer options:(__bridge NSDictionary *)attachments];
  if (attachments)
    CFRelease(attachments);

  NSNumber *orientation = (__bridge NSNumber *)(CMGetAttachment(imageDataSampleBuffer, kCGImagePropertyOrientation, NULL));
  NSArray *features = [[CIDetector detectorOfType:CIDetectorTypeFace context:nil options:@{ CIDetectorAccuracy: CIDetectorAccuracyHigh }] featuresInImage:ciImage options:@{ CIDetectorImageOrientation: orientation }];
  if (features.count == 1) {
    CIFaceFeature *faceFeature = [features firstObject];
    CGRect faceRect = faceFeature.bounds;

    CGImageRef tempImage = [[CIContext contextWithOptions:nil] createCGImage:ciImage fromRect:ciImage.extent];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:tempImage scale:1.0 orientation:orientation.intValue];
    UIImage *face = [image extractFace:faceRect];
  }  
}
```

where extractFace is an extension of UIImage:

```
- (UIImage *)extractFace:(CGRect)rect {
  rect = CGRectMake(rect.origin.x * self.scale,
                  rect.origin.y * self.scale,
                  rect.size.width * self.scale,
                  rect.size.height * self.scale);
  CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(self.CGImage, rect);
  UIImage *result = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef scale:self.scale orientation:self.imageOrientation];
  CGImageRelease(imageRef);
  return result;
}
```

Creating video output:

```
AVCaptureVideoDataOutput *videoOutput = [[AVCaptureVideoDataOutput alloc] init];
videoOutput.videoSettings = @{ (id)kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey: [NSNumber numberWithInt:kCMPixelFormat_32BGRA] };
videoOutput.alwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames = YES;
self.videoOutputQueue = dispatch_queue_create("OutputQueue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
[videoOutput setSampleBufferDelegate:self queue:self.videoOutputQueue];
[self.session addOutput:videoOutput];
```

Comment: but how to call didOutputSampleBuffer from didOutputMetadataObjects method ?

Comment: You don't have to. If video output is added to the session as I've described above, only didOutputSampleBuffer will be called automatically in the created queue.

Answer (score 1):

```
- (UIImage *) screenshot {

CGSize size = CGSizeMake(faceFrame.frame.size.width, faceFrame.frame.size.height);

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, NO, [UIScreen     mainScreen].scale);

CGRect rec = CGRectMake(faceFrame.frame.origin.x, faceFrame.frame.orogin.y, faceFrame.frame.size.width, faceFrame.frame.size.height);
[_viewController.view drawViewHierarchyInRect:rec   afterScreenUpdates:YES];

UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
return image;
}
```

Take some cue from above

```
  let contextImage: UIImage = <<screenshot>>!
let cropRect: CGRect = CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)
let imageRef: CGImageRef =     CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(contextImage.CGImage, cropRect)
let image: UIImage = UIImage(CGImage: imageRef, scale:   originalImage.scale, orientation: originalImage.imageOrientation)!
```

Comment: tried a lot with your suggestion. 'screenshot' returns empty image as I understood, next part of code - where did 'originalImage' come from? here's the code I've: http://pastebin.com/M2CFPzDj (face = screenshot()). It always have different size and length, but as Image it's empty :c

Comment: and what coordinates and size must be in cropRect? origin.x/y and size.width/height from faceFrameView?

Comment: crashes on
let imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(contextImage.CGImage, cropRect)!

Comment: the problem that screenshot can't be made on sublayer

Comment: Sounds like you want to render your layer into a UIImage. In that case, the method below should do the trick. Just add this to your view or controller class, or create a category on CALayer.

    - (UIImage *)imageFromLayer:(CALayer *)layer
    {
      UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(layer.frame.size, NO, 0);

      [layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
      UIImage *outputImage =     UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

      UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

      return outputImage;
    }

Comment: @SwiftStudier  http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/115302-converting-calayer-masks-to-an-image.html   check out this link

Comment: i get empty screenshot too

Comment: As I remember I moved the tracking logic to backend and used the full screenshot which came correctly (I stopped trying to extract the face from it)

Comment: @SwiftStudier could you provide code how to get full screenshot in didOutputMetadataObjects method ?

Comment: Seems that I don't have this project anymore, sorry

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest to use `UIImagePickerController` class to implement your custom camera for picking multiple image for face detection. Please do check Apple's sample code [PhotoPicker](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/PhotoPicker/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010196).

To some up use `UIImagePickerController`for launching camera as sourceType. And handle its delegate `imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:` to capture image + you can also check `takePicture`function if it helps